# AWS Cloudformation how from S3 bucket names CommaDelimitedList make list of ARN - semi for loop cycle

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Here are parameters - S3 bucket names list:

```
Parameters:
  S3BucketNames:
    Description: Enter S3 Bucket Names
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Default: my-first-bucket,testing-bucket,codepipeline-bucket
```

Need to make policy IAM Policy for GetObject, PutObject operations, when arn has to be in the following format suitable for IAM policy:

```
arn:${Partition}:s3:::${BucketName}/${ObjectName}
```

In my example it should look like:

```
"arn:aws:s3:::my-first-bucket/*",
"arn:aws:s3:::testing-bucket/*",
"arn:aws:s3:::codepipeline-bucket/*"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to think a bit how I can pull it off, obvious when you know it, but maybe will be helpfull for someone:

```
  S3RolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: DemoPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:GetObject
            Resource: !Split
            - ","
            - !Sub
              - arn:aws:s3:::${S3Middle}/*
              - S3Middle: !Join [ "/*,arn:aws:s3:::" , !Ref S3BucketNames ]
```

It's not a full CloudFormation template - just sample peace

Comment: Clever little hack!